# Implementing PayPal discounts - what if the user cancels?

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart, discount

Alright, I got my Paypal shopping cart set up and working, now I'd like to be able to add discount coupons.
I know I can simply implement the 'discount_amount_cart' variable in my form, but I'm still a little lost when it comes to handling the deactivation of a coupon code.

Let's say A activates the code. Now in my database it will be marked as 'reserved', meaning no one else can use it. Once A completes his transaction, the IPN will mark the code as 'used' and it becomes useless.
But what if A decides to activate the code, but never actually buys anything on my website?

I'm using the $_SESSION variable to save my shopping cart, so once the user returns to my website, the code might still be shown as activated for him. When exactly would I mark it back as 'not reserved & not used' in my database?
I could do this based on time, but this doesn't really feel safe either. Let's say the user puts everything into his basket, goes to Paypal, waits for an hour and then decides to finish his checkout. The discount would still be activated, but in the meantime, it could've already been 'unreserved' in the database and used by another person!?

How would I go about this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this has little to do with PayPal and more about your business rules. If your coupon is single use (globally), then you will be faced with the same issue regardless of any payment flow.

- Simply putting it in "cart" and/or *any event* where a user "activates" said coupon, then just navigating elsewhere in your site, doesn't do anything, [whatever], creates that *lag*
- it could be Paypal, Amazon, your own gateway - it really doesn't matter...but there will be a lag between activation and payment (beyond your control)

I think it's just best to be explicit with your customers and handle it appropriately technically (based on what that explicit messaging is).

You'll see some implementation of "timed purchase" at ticketing sites (e.g. buying a ticket to a game, movie, etc.) - they will have a "timer" for the user to do something (otherwise, the "reservation" is lost).

Hth...

Comment: Ok, I see how I could implement that. The problem which remains is: as soon as the user moves to Paypal to finish his payment, I lose control. Lets say he stays on Paypal for a while, in the meantime the timer runs out and then he finishes his payment. The Instan Payment Notification would find out that his coupon code isnt valid anymore and progress a failed payment (he wouldve sent me the money already though at that point). What could I do about that? Thanks so far..

Comment: @proGrammar It's still your business rule. You could cancel/refund/void, or **not** "execute"/"authorize"/"confirm"/"capture" (depending on which API you are implementing) based on whatever business rule you have in place. How strict/complex those will be is up to you...Hth...

Answer (score 0):

Put an expiry date on coupon use - such as must be used within 10 days of activation. It gives the user urgency to use the coupon and gives you a timeframe to invalidate it.